# Random problems being able to vote

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Sometimes when I load a question and want to vote on it, the up/down button isn't clickable. The cursor **does** change to the pointer, clicking has no effect. This has only appeared lately in the last few days and appears to be random. A page reload fixes the issue.

Firefox 40.0.03 (with adblock edge), Windows 8.1

**Update**:
I've also found that the two alert buttons in the status bar at the top of the screen (one for notifications and one for rep changes) don't open up their specific div's when clicked, so I'm guessing it's a JS not fully loading properly problem?

**Update 2 - Reproducing**
I've been able to reproduce by opening the main list of questions page, and opening approx 50 of the questions in new tabs and waiting for them to load.

**Console Errors**
On a page that it's happened, the errors shown were:

```
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined wrong-inexact-intersection-between-3d-triangles-cgal:1061:1
ReferenceError: $ is not defined wrong-inexact-intersection-between-3d-triangles-cgal:1068:9
```

I think that's a classic sign of Jquery not being loading? I don't have the cache disabled in my Firefox.

Interestingly, I also sometimes see:

```
The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading. full.en.js:1:0
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/. full.en.js:1:0
no element found 8502:1:1
TypeError: n.data is undefined wmd.en.js:2:24550
```

Comment: Userscripts?​​​

Comment: @TinyGiant Nope. Only the webdev toolbar and adblock edge. I haven't updated either lately.

Comment: Don't understand why someone would downvote this. Other than they couldn't reproduce it, but not everyone is going to be able to reproduce every bug. Anyway, the dev team will take a look at this eventually. If it happens again, see if you can get a screen capture (preferably video) of it happening and include that in your post.

Comment: @TinyGiant Will do, though there isn't much to see other than the cursor not changing to the pointer. I'm middle-clicking on questions to open in a new tab if that may have any effect?

Comment: That *shouldn't* affect anything, the reason for including the screen capture would be most useful to prove that you are actually seeing this bug. Some users think that if they cannot reproduce a bug then it doesn't exist. Other users report bugs that don't actually exist just to waste people's time, not very often but it does happen.

Comment: Sure will do. It happens, maybe twice a day, approx 1 in 80 page loads for me?

Comment: @TinyGiant Just had it happen to me - updated the question to reflect that cursor does change to the pointer, but clicking has no effect on the score

Comment: Does clicking "expand more comments" on such a page just pop you to the top, without actually expanding?  If so, this is a bug that I've also experienced occasionally.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, next time it happens press ctrl+shift+j to open the browser console, include any errors in blockquotes in your question, that will go a long way to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: *A page reload fixes the issue.* - Does reloading the page show your vote from already clicking it or does reloading just allow you to click it again to vote?

Comment: @BSMP no the vote is not registered the reload then the click registers the vote.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've not had it happen on a page with an "expand more comments" so unable to test that. Next time it happens I will look out for it though

Comment: @TinyGiant Last two times it happened, I had a look in the console window and there were no errors listed there.

Answer (score 3):

We've tightened up our "cross-site request forgery" checking in the last few days. If your page has an expired `fkey` value, voting won't work. Presumably, the page reload which you say makes things work grabs the correct, current `fkey` value.

If you have newly loaded (and fully loaded) pages where voting doesn't work, and have a way to consistently reproduce it, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: Would this explain the message I received once early this morning (GMT time) at the top of the screen in a red bar stating something along the lines of "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

Comment: I tried grepping for that and related strings in our code, but couldn't find anything. :-(

Comment: Updated original comment with the exact string! It just happened again. Worth pointing out that when that bar is shown, the clicking actions fail as described

Comment: That message is shown if jQuery failed to load (it's loaded from Google Hosted Libraries). Unfortunately, if that happens, none of our JS will work, and you will have to reload the page.

Comment: @ChrisJesterYoung - updated question with details of how to reproduce the problem. Sometimes the message is shown, other times not.

Comment: @user3791372 Not sure how well your browser caches the copy of jQuery downloaded from Google Hosted Libraries, but if it doesn't, opening 50 tabs at once could explain why some of those tabs don't load it successfully.

Comment: @ChristJesterYoung I think that may be affirmative. I've just checked the console, and saw two errors that hint at jquery not being loaded - updated question.